# XSLT not selecting some elements when namespace added

Tags: xml, xslt

When I add namespaces to the headers of my document, the XPath expression fails for some of the elements.  Solutions elsewhere on stackOverflow suggest adding the namespace to the elements.  However, I already have namespaces in the XPath.  The elements that are failing are different in two ways.  1) they have multiple entries for the XPath and 2) they have an additional level down in the element hierarchy.

The source document is (i have edited for brevity):

```
<ns0:SubscriptionNotification xmlns:ns1="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/rightnow/StudentJSEndpoint_REQUEST/types">
    <ns0:Organization>
       <ns2:Addresses>
         <ns2:TypedAddressList action="action16">
            <ns2:City>City13</ns2:City> <!-- Xpath works -->
            <ns2:Country>
               <ns1:ID id="id18"/>
               <ns1:Name>Name17</ns1:Name>
            </ns2:Country> <!-- Xpath does not work -->
            <ns2:Country xsi:type="NamedReadOnlyID" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <ns1:ID id="id20"/>
               <ns1:Name>Name19</ns1:Name>
            </ns2:Country>

         </ns2:TypedAddressList> 
      </ns2:Addresses>
      <ns2:Name>Name8</ns2:Name>

   </ns0:Organization>
</ns0:SubscriptionNotification>
```

The XSL that has the namespace header and does not find the Country attributes is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/rightnow/StudentJSEndpoint_REQUEST/types">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <nstrgmpr:createAccount xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/commonService/" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/osc/StudentBBEndpoint_REQUEST/types" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:errors="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/" xmlns:types="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/accountService/types/" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/osc/StudentBBEndpoint_REQUEST" xmlns:orafault="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/oracle-fault-11_0" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/accountService/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <nstrgmpr:account>
            <tns:OrganizationName>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Name"/>
            </tns:OrganizationName>
            <tns:PrimaryAddress>
                <nsmpr1:AddressLine1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Street"/>
                </nsmpr1:AddressLine1>
                <nsmpr1:City>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:City"/>
                </nsmpr1:City>
                <nsmpr1:Country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Country/ns1:Name"/>
                </nsmpr1:Country>
                <nsmpr1:PostalCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:PostalCode"/>
                </nsmpr1:PostalCode>
                <nsmpr1:State>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:StateOrProvince/ns1:Name"/>
                </nsmpr1:State>
            </tns:PrimaryAddress>
        </nstrgmpr:account>
    </nstrgmpr:createAccount>
</xsl:template>
```

Working XLS that does not contain the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/rightnow/StudentJSEndpoint_REQUEST/types">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <createAccount>
        <account>
            <OrganizationName><xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Name"/></OrganizationName>
            <PrimaryAddress>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Street"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:City"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Country/ns1:Name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:PostalCode"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:StateOrProvince/ns1:Name"/>
            </PrimaryAddress>
        </account>
    </createAccount>
</xsl:template>
```

there must be something that handles the XPath differently between the attributes, but I don't know XSLT well enough to identify the issue.  It is the ns in the createAccount that seems to cause the problem. If I remove it, the transform works. But I need it as part of the output, so I don't see how I can remove it.

Comment: What are you declaring in your XSLT header? Consider posting full code.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the issue:  this means a **complete** stylesheet (preferably minimized to show only the problem), and the expected result.

Comment: specifically, how is the ns2 prefix declared in the XSLT code from which you posted the second snippet? is it the same namespace URI as for the ns2 namespace in the XML? remember that for matching, what matters is the namespace URI, not the namespace prefix.

Comment: @dret7 - thank you, I was not aware of that.  However, both ns2 prefixes point to  xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3".

Comment: further research showed that the suggested target XML has sample namespaces, not the real ones.  So, the problem is technically unfeasible.  But the solution definitely helps me understand what is happening under the covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have two conflicting namespace declarations binding the `ns1` prefix to two different URIs.

In the `xsl:stylesheet` element you declare:

```
xmlns:ns1="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3"
```

but then in `nstrgmpr:createAccount` you override this by declaring:

```
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/osc/StudentBBEndpoint_REQUEST"
```

When you use the `ns1` prefix in the XPath expression selecting the Country, it is the latter declaration that is in scope - and therefore nothing is being selected.

The solution is to use a different prefix in the first declaration- for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns9="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/rightnow/StudentJSEndpoint_REQUEST/types">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <nstrgmpr:createAccount xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/commonService/" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/osc/StudentBBEndpoint_REQUEST/types" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:errors="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/" xmlns:types="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/accountService/types/" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/osc/StudentBBEndpoint_REQUEST" xmlns:orafault="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/oracle-fault-11_0" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/crmCommon/salesParties/accountService/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <nstrgmpr:account>
            <tns:OrganizationName>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Name"/>
            </tns:OrganizationName>
            <tns:PrimaryAddress>
                <nsmpr1:AddressLine1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Street"/>
                </nsmpr1:AddressLine1>
                <nsmpr1:City>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:City"/>
                </nsmpr1:City>

                <nsmpr1:Country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:Country/ns9:Name"/>
                </nsmpr1:Country>

                <nsmpr1:PostalCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:PostalCode"/>
                </nsmpr1:PostalCode>
                <nsmpr1:State>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SubscriptionNotification/ns0:Organization/ns2:Addresses/ns2:TypedAddressList/ns2:StateOrProvince/ns1:Name"/>
                </nsmpr1:State>
            </tns:PrimaryAddress>
        </nstrgmpr:account>
    </nstrgmpr:createAccount>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also that the input has two `Country` nodes - but in XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction will only return the value of the first node in the selected node-set.